# Parallel Ajax calls stop the window scroll for fraction of seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, asynchronous

While loading a webpage, there are multiple ajax calls are running parallelly. Few of the ajax calls will respond soon. But one ajax call its taking sometime(around 10seconds) to complete it..

Please find the below mockup page:[image]

Sample code:

```
request1();
request2();
request3();
request4();
request5();
```

From the above example, `Request 3` takes sometime to load the data. but `Request 1, 2, 4 & 5` were responding quickly. Meanwhile, I can see the scrollbar in a page. but it doesn't allow the user to scroll down. Because still its waiting for `Request 3` to complete it.

There is no dependencies in any of those ajax calls. Then why its blocking the scrolling until all the requests are done?

Thanks in advance.